# Converting a rlogin command into an alias

Tags: linux, shell, alias, csh

I work on multiple machines and need to login into them remotely. I want to have an alias which can make my rlogin command simpler.

So, I want to convert following command into an alias :

```
rlogin `echo "machine $num" | tr -d ' '`
```

I tried writing this in my .cshrc file :

```
alias rl rlogin `echo machine$1| tr -d ' '`
```

when I do `rl 13`

It says :

```
usage: rlogin [ -8EL] [-e char] [ -l username ] host
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Not sure whether you are missing a space between `inmodel` and `$1`?

Comment: results in same error when I do alias rl rlogin `echo machine $1| tr -d ' '`

Comment: Okay, the problem might be `$1`. For aliases, the syntax for the first argument seems to be `!:1`. You may have to escape it to `\!:1`.

Comment: I suggest reading through ["Writing Aliases in `csh` and `tcsh`"](http://home.adelphi.edu/sbloch/class/archive/271/fall2005/notes/aliases.html), which is a sort of cookbook for writing aliases that include complex features such as pipes and command-substitution.

Comment: same result with this : alias rl  rlogin `echo machine \!:1| tr -d ' '`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily see the alias is not defined as intended, by running `alias rl`:

```
% alias rl rlogin `echo machine$1| tr -d ' '`
% alias rl
rlogin machine
```

There are two problems with the way you define your alias.

First, when defining an alias like this:

```
alias rl rlogin `...`
```

the `...` command is evaluated at the time the alias is *defined*, while you need to defer the evaluation to the time it is used.  The correct way to do it is to encapsulate everything in single quotes, like

```
'`...`'
```

(Also, we need to replace the internal single-quotes with double-quotes, in order not to clash with the outer single-quotes).

Second, you need to use `\!*` instead of `$1`.

So you get:

```
% alias rl rlogin '`echo machine\!* | tr -d " "`'
% alias rl
rlogin `echo machine!* | tr -d " "`
```

Comment: Thanks! works for me. Although you answered it first and also explained my mistakes but solution by @devnull is really simple, so I am a little confused which answer to accept. I have upvoted both the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: don't beat yourself up over it! ;)

Answer (score 6):

The `tr` pipeline in your alias is useless.  Simply saying:

```
alias rl 'rlogin machine\!:1'
```

and invoking it by saying:

```
rl 42
```

should work, i.e. should issue `rlogin machine42`.

Note that you need to escape the `!` in order to prevent it from being interpreted by the shell for history expansion.